# python3 nodejs docker images

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am working with a django angular project. I am using python3 so I want a container where node 6.4.0 and python3 will be installed. I have node:6.4.0 and python:3.4 images in my docker.

Now I want another images named py3node.
I am trying this way:

1. Dockerfile:

   ```
   FROM node:6.4.0
   FROM python:3.4
   ```
2. docker build -t py3node

   ```
   output:

   Sending build context to Docker daemon 8.192 kB
   Step 1 : FROM node:6.4.0
   ---> 800da22d0e7b
   Step 2 : FROM python:3.4
   ---> 93bc8e41eb8c
   Successfully built 93bc8e41eb8c
   ```

Then I run:

```
docker run -it py3node /bin/bash

root@092724f514:/# node -v

output:
bash: node: command not found
```

But python3 works. Why node:6.4.0 is not working?

Answer (score 5):

You must choose one image and install everything on top of it. In your case I would do it like:

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:6.4.0
RUN apt-get update || : && apt-get install python -y
RUN apt-get install python3-pip -y
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't combine images like this and expect it to work! ([Using multiple `FROM` directives is hazardous and should probably be removed](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/13026)).

You either want to start with a generic image (ubuntu? alpine?) and install python and node, or start with a django friendly image [here maybe?](https://hub.docker.com/_/django/). I'd look at how other django+docker projects are doing things.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to : [node:7.9-alpine unable to build package due python is not installed](https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/issues/384)

All you need to is to add the following to your DockerFile

```
RUN apk --no-cache add g++ gcc libgcc libstdc++ linux-headers make python
RUN npm install --quiet node-gyp -g
```